# How to Implement Spoofing GPS location ios-app?

Tags: ios, iphone, location, spoofing

Is possible to implement a location spoofer app (hijack location service) on iOS? (not for debugging), if yes, any tip will be well come.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, it's impossible to make a location spoofer for iOS unless your iPhone is jailbroken but you can spoof your iPhone location without jailbreak using PC or Mac.

If you want to develop a tweak that spoofs your location you need to hook `CLLocation`.